# Restrict ipv6 access

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have this node/express app running on heroku. I need to save the ip addresses of the visitors.

I've set the the trust proxy to be true in the application
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

```
app.set('trust proxy' , true);
```

And then in my endpoint I am retrieving ip address from request object as req.ip

```
app.post('/api/send-data', (req, res) => {

let data;

// find the user's ip address

const ip = req.ip;

console.log(request came from ${ip});
}
```

It's working fine but the problem is `req.ip` return either **ipv6** or **ipv4** and I only want to save **ipv4** of the user, how can I do that?

I've read the node/express documentation and set my app to receive requests from ipv4

`app.listen(port, 0.0.0.0)`

But still I am seeing requests from **IPV6** addresses. Is it because the request goes to heroku router first before coming to the application and heroku router pass the ip of the user in x-forwarded header so application always consider it a request from ipv4? If so any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

[Expedited WAF](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/expeditedwaf) addon may help you, as it states that :

[image]